# RPM: macros for /usr/local prefix

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have not found in https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/RPMMacros/ any details on macros that can operate with directory hieararchy under `/usr/local`.

Does this exist, or the best I can have in my spec file is something like this?

```
%files
%{_prefix}/local/etc/my_app.cfg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `/usr/local/` is discouraged by Fedora; if you're using RPMs with unique names, you'll never have to worry about conflicting with globally installed software.

From https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines :

> In addition, no Fedora package can contain files or directories or modify files under ... `/usr/local` as these directories are not permitted to be used by Distributions in the FHS

So to answer your question *explicitly*, no there is no macro because they don't want you to use that location.